# Android: full-width SearchView in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want a SearchView to fully take up the full width of the ActionBar (support v7), but even after calling...

```
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

... I get a blank space to the left:

[image: Search bar]

Comment: visit this answer this may help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867854/actionbar-searchview-not-fully-expanding-in-landscape-mode

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by using a Toolbar and setting the following paramters:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tbToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">
```

Inside that you can put a SearchView or use your toolbar items with a menu.xml which has a toolbarview. See the android developer docs.